# jQuery click not firing on an image

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery is not working as expected. I'm simply trying to fire an event when an image is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("document.ready has fired");

    $("img").click(function () {
        alert("image has been clicked");
    });
});
```

I see the "document.ready has fired" alert when the page loads, so jQuery and my custom .js file are referenced correctly.

I suspect I'm missing something really obvious, but what?

**Update:**
The jQuery is correct (works in a new page but not on my existing page), as I workaround for now I have used the `onclick` on the `<img>` tag since this had to be a 'quick fix', I will look into what has happened though, thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: do your all image load with page load?

Comment: Yes - I see all my images. The page looks to have loaded correctly.

Comment: D you have a link, any console errors?

Comment: Do you have any div that may be overlapping the images?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f6JbH/ - works

Comment: OK - So the jQuery is correct, thanks guys for validating. I have gotten around it with using an `onclick` - but will try and figure out the root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use jQuery's bind function as then if anythings dynamically changed in the DOM it will still pick up the event as I've also had issues in the past using jQuery's .click function which resulted in this same problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("document.ready has fired");

    $("img").bind('click', function () {
        alert("image has been clicked");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case all your images arent loaded direclty on page load you can try this

```
$(window).load(function () {
    alert("window.load has fired");

    $("img").click(function () {
        alert("image has been clicked");
    });
});
```

or

```
$("body").on("click", "img", function () {...
```

Comment: The image doesn't need to be loaded, or even have a `src`, in order to add event listeners to it.

Comment: @Esailija True, but if theyre added to the dom dynamically, the last row could be an option

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

Try this:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function () {
        alert("image has been clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice but because the selector in the original code ("img") it will pickup all img elements anyway and only creating 1 job record if you like where as this will make many records to do the exact same job. Hope that's of help :)